# UITableView change background color of specific cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the color of a UITableView cell. I have this code but it doesn't work. Can someone explain to me **why** and what I should change?

```
[_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:myIndexAsInt inSection:0]].contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of a standard `UITableViewCell` you need to do that by overriding the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDispayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDispayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

If your cell has custom content you might want to have a slightly different implementation.

Comment: How do I use the int variable of the index I want to color in all that? For example, the 3rd cell.

Comment: You do not set the int variable of anything. You check the `row` and `section` properties of the `NSIndexPath` object passed to that method and make decisions based on their value. e.g. `cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row ? whiteColor : redColor;`

Answer (score 0):

to set the 3rd cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   if (indexPath.row == 2)
   {
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Cell background colors must be set in the `willDisplayCell` delegate method. Besides that, you need to reset the color for all other rows otherwise as the table is scrolled and cells are reused the background color will appear in other rows.

Comment: That's not true. I have a simple test code running and tested that 
it can be done from (actually literally anywhere but...let's see the list)
1) cellForrowAtIndexPath
2) didSelectRowAtIndexPath
3) target-action method from a unbutton
...I could come up with any number of solutions..NSnotification...block..etc..etc.. :)

Comment: @EarlGrey It's right in the docs for `UITableViewCell` (and reinforced by my own experience): "If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate."

Comment: You are saying "This won't work". That's the thing I am contradicting. Regardless of what the docs say/recommend, there are other solutions.
Much better solution is to have a custom UITableViewCell subclass with configureWithObject:(SomeClass *)paramClass and let the cell set the correct color itself based the passed object.
So the Apple's example is far from perfect as it ties the color setting to the view controller, the encapsulation is broken. Why expose that thing at all to outside world.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code itself is ok syntacticaly.

Some things cannot be verified from my side. Please put a breakpoint on that line and run it.

0) By putting a breakpoint there, and seeing the system stop there, you actually check that that line is executed.

1) If step 0 was ok, check that you actually have an instance of table view (it must NOT be nil, maybe if you are using nibs, you forgot to create an IBoutlet).

2) Make sure the tableView has proper delegate and datasource. (usually the ViewController where those things you mention are handled...)

3) check that you are passing a proper type and proper value for the myIndexAsInt argument. It should be of NSInteger type and should be equal 2.

4) If all 3 above are ok, perhaps you are calling it from a wrong place.

Let us know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an variable to hold the index position. So after your **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** delegate called just set the index position in that variable and reload the table. Use a condition in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** datasource method to check for index position and now set the background colour for that specific cell.

in **.h** file:

```
NSInteger indexPos;
```

in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** delegate:

```
indexPos = indexPath.row;
```

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
if (indexPath.row == indexPos) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```